# Diagonalizable Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Is there a way to generate N x N random diagonalizable matrix in MATLAB? I tried as following:

N = 10;
A = diag(rand(N,N))

but it is giving me an N x 1 matrix. I also need the matrix to be symmetric.

Comment: diagnosable -> diagonalizable? Also, what should the distribution be?

Comment: @user3598116, did one of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are considering real-valued matrices: Every real symmetric matrix is [diagonalizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable#Diagonalizable_matrices). You can therefore randomly generate some matrix `A`, e.g. by using `A = rand(N, N)`, and then symmetrize it, e.g. by

```
A = A + A'
```

For complex matrices the condition for diagonalizability is that the matrix is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). If `A` is an arbitrary square random matrix, you can normalize it by

```
A = A * A'
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>All full-rank matrices are diagonalizable by SVD or eigen-decomposition.</strike>

If you want a random symmetric matrix...

```
N = 5
V = rand(N*(N+1)/2, 1)

M = triu(ones(N))
M(M==1) = V
M = M + tril(M.',-1)
```

@DavidEisenstat is right.  I tried his example.  Sorry for the false statement.  Here's a true statement that is relevant specifically to your situation, but is not as general:  Random matrices are virtually guaranteed to be diagonalizable.

Comment: "All full-rank matrices are diagonalizable" No, e.g., {{x, 1}, {0, x}} is not diagonalizable but of full rank when x != 0.

Comment: What do you mean by virtually guaranteed? Take the matrix from @DavidEisenstat and set x as random. How is this random matrix "virtually guaranteed" to be diagonalizable?

Comment: That is a very specific matrix form.  When I say "random matrix", I mean a matrix constructed as in my example. (Each element in the upper triangle is iid from random uniform, lower triangle is a copy.)